# Problem with polyglossia behaviour for LuaLaTeX 1.0.4. Possible bug?

Tags: luatex, languages, polyglossia, cyrillic

With LuaLaTeX I had compiled the same code by different distributions:

> LuaLaTeX 0.95.0/TeXLive 2016
>
> LuaLaTeX 1.0.4/MiKTeX 2.9.6236

updated to the latest versions.

Unfortunately, I got different results for `polyglossia` behaviour.

With the following code:

---

```
%%============================ Compiler Directives =======================%%
%%                                                                        %%
% !TeX program = lualatex                                    
% !TeX encoding = utf8
% !TeX spellcheck = uk_UA

\documentclass{article}

%%============================ languagee ann encodings ===================%%

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{ukrainian}
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

%%========================================================================%%

\begin{document}

Some text

Якийсь текст

Какой-то текст

\end{document}
```

---

LuaLaTeX 0.95.0/TeXLive 2016  works fine.

---

But LuaLaTeX 1.0.4/MiKTeX 2.9.6236 produce an error:

```
! Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain the Cyrillic script!
(polyglossia)                Please define \cyrillicfont with \newfontfamily.

See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.
```

Main question is: **Why only with `LuaLaTeX 1.0.4/MiKTeX 2.9.6236` should I use any other nonintuitive constructions for using fonts differ from Latin?**

Is this a bug of LuaLaTeX 1.0.4?

I note that in selected fonts the necessary symbols are present.

[log-file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B38PMqn0yNv-MXpNZHAyd01NZVE)

Comment: The error message is only issued when you add `\texttt{...}` in a Ukrainian context. And it does also in TeX Live, of course. Solution: `\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{<some monospaced font supporting Cyrillic>}`. I guess some specific MiKTeX configuration file kicks in, but it's unimportant, as the declaration above is needed whenever the font set with `\setmonofont` has no specific support for Cyrillic.

Comment: @egreg My`TeXLive`  works fine even with `\texttt{...}` and the preamble. Just checked

Comment: Then the problem is in the font. Sorry, but I don't have Consolas.

Comment: @egreg I had try `\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{Consolas}` and got the same error with `MikTeX`.

Comment: @egreg Just cheched `xelatex/MikTeX` with MWE preamble. Works fine. I think, the problem in MikTeX's`LuaLaTeX`

Comment: @egreg I slitly change the focus of the question

Comment: I also tried with LuaLaTeX in TeX Live 2017/pretest (which has LuaTeX 1.0.4) and the result is the same: the error only appears if I add `\texttt` to the document.

Comment: @egreg Problem in `LuaLaTeX` vers. 1.0.4

Comment: Can you show the log-file?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I had added (the bottom of the post)

Comment: I get no error  with luatex 1.04 even if i repeat the text in `\ttfamily`

Comment: Hm. There is something fishy with your fonts. What happens if you remove the local times.ttf (E:/Projects/LaTeX/Z_LaTeX_XP/Fizmatlit/localtexmf/fonts/truetype/times.ttf) and delete/remove the times.luc and times.lua file in the luatex cache?

Comment: Btw: It works for me, but I have here miktex next, I can test with the normal miktex only tomorrow.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I removed (E:/Projects/LaTeX/Z_LaTeX_XP/Fizmatlit/localtexmf/fonts/tru‌​etype/times.ttf) and, it seems, the error has disappeared.

Comment: You should also check the locations of the other fonts, the messages in the log looks fishy for them too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just removed all problematic localtexmf. Thank you. We still need to see the log from egreg, there was also arose same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your log-file one can see that you are using a local version of times.ttf, in `E:/Projects/LaTeX/Z_LaTeX_XP/Fizmatlit/localtexmf/fonts/truetype/times.ttf` and one can also see that this font doesn't has correct Script features:

```
. fontspec info: "no-scripts"
. 
. Font "TimesNewRoman" does not contain any OpenType `Script' information.
```

So it is quite probable that the font is faulty, and as it is in a `localtexmf` is is also probable that only your miktex system is using it which would explain why only miktex doesn't work. This types of errors depends normally on a concrete font file, and so can be easily system and font dependant.

Answer (score 2):

works with LuaTeX 1.0.4:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.9,FakeStretch=0.9]{Consolas}
\newfontface\cyrillicfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{ukrainian}
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}

    Some text

    Якийсь текст

    Какой-то текст

\ttfamily   
    Some text

    Якийсь текст

    Какой-то текст
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, with `\usepackage{libertine}` very well. But, what if I want to use a system font? (I use Win10)

Comment: You have to use a font which has the cyrillic letters. Times has no one!